# how can i click the value of li element of embedded li class(some-menu-item-optional-value)

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I want to click the third value(embedded li element) given the below code snippet, any help?

some-menu-title-value

some-menu-item-default-value

some-menu-item-optional-value

Comment: Please give HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the element will always be the 2nd `<li>` element, you can use:
`element.all(by.css('li')).get(1).click();`

If there are other `<li>` elements on the page, you can refine the css selector like:
`element.all(by.css('li.some-menu-items')).get(1).click();`

Its hard to tell from the HTML provided, but if your elements are nested like so:

```
<div class="myClass"
    <li class="myClass"
        <li class="myClass"</li>
    </li>
</div>
```

Then you could do `element(by.css('div>li>li')).click();` to click the inner `<li>` element.